# How to implement DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL in cx_Oracle and python3 and get the ddl of the table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

this is the oracle command i am using :-

```
query = '''SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE', 'MY_SCHEMA') FROM DUAL;'''
cur.execute(query)
```

now how to get the ddl of the table using `cx_Oracle` and `python3` .

please help . i am unable to extract the ddl.

Answer (score 2):

The following code can be used to fetch the contents of the DDL from dbms_metadata:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@hostname/myservice")
cursor = conn.cursor()

def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.CLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.LONG_STRING, arraysize = cursor.arraysize)

cursor.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler
cursor.execute("select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', :tableName) from dual",
        tableName="THE_TABLE_NAME")
text, = cursor.fetchone()
print("DDL fetched of length:", len(text))
print(text)
```

The use of the output type handler is to eliminate the need to process the CLOB. Without it you would need to do `str(lob)` or `lob.read()` in order to get at its contents. Either way, however, you are not limited to 4,000 characters.

Comment: thank you Anthony for learning this, that's very nice answer, I deleted mine.

Comment: No problem! Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

cx_Oracle has native support for calling PL/SQL.

Assuming you have connection and cursor object, the snippet will look like this:

```
binds = dict(object_type='TABLE', name='DUAL', schema='SYS')
ddl = cursor.callfunc('DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL', keywordParameters=binds, returnType=cx_Oracle.CLOB)
print(ddl)
```

You don't need to split the DDL in 4k/32k chunks, as Python's `str` doesn't have this limitation. In order to get the DDL in one chunk, just set `returnType` to `cx_Oracle.CLOB`. You can later convert it to `str` by doing `str(ddl)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for all your efforts . Sir can you please suggest where can i learn advanced cx_Oracle in python3

Comment: @HemaVarunKumarPenaganti the docs are pretty good for a starting point https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/